# CSS3 Box Shadow on Top, Left, and Right Only

Tags: css

Greetings,

I am trying to apply a CSS3 box shadow to only the top, right, and left of a DIV with a radius that matches the result of the following CSS (minus the bottom shadow)

```
 #div {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
This shadow will be applied to a nav bar on a page, the bar is positioned on the top of the main container DIV. What I am trying to accomplish is to continue the box shadow of the main DIV onto the nav bar, which sits above it, but without a bottom shadow on the nav bar. Take a look at the [site itself](http://innovideoproductions.com) to see what I'm talking about, easier than adding all of the HTML and CSS here.

**UPDATE 2**
Since the DIV I am working with is singular, rather than trying to place a shadow on each nav li, I elected to change it to the following:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 7px #e6e6e6;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -4px 7px #e6e6e6;
    box-shadow: 0px -4px 7px #e6e6e6;
```

This makes the top of the shadow very noticeable but it's what I am trying to accomplish - if anyone knows of a way to keep the shadow the same in appearance to the container DIV, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, rather than making yet another edit - tweaked it a tiny bit and it's a lot closer now - `0px -2.6px 7px #e6e6e6;`. I wish I had fiddled with the positioning more before posting but I'm fairly new to CSS3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's better if you just cover the bottom part with another div and you will get consistent drop shadow across the board.

```
#servicesContainer {
  /*your css*/
  position: relative;
}
```

and it's fixed! like magic!

Comment: Thanks :) Accepted as solution since it technically fixes the problem of the shadow under the nav appearing over the `#mainContainer` DIV but it actually ended up generating another problem - the shadow from `#mainContainer` overlapping the nav bar. Same problem, different location lol. Oh well

Comment: I didn't catch it, probably because I'm viewing it on Chrome. You can add a new div at the top of #servicesContainer, give it a background-color of #2A0808; and the apply position: relative to the new div. It will achieve the same effect without overlapping the shadow.

Answer (score 30):

use the spread value...

box-shadow has the following values

```
box-shadow: x y blur spread color;
```

so you could use something like..

```
box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px -10px black;
```

**UPDATE:** i'm adding a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/YXjQa/)

Answer (score 15):

You can give multiple values to **box-shadow** property

 eg

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px 0px #000,
                    0px -10px 12px 0px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px 0px #000,
                    0px -10px 12px 0px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px 0px #000,
            0px -10px 12px 0px #000;
```

it is drop shadow to **left** and **right** only, you can adapt it to your requirements

Comment: This is great, this hides my bottom shadow(overlays white shadow on it) box-shadow: 0px 8px 0px -1px #FFFFFF, 0px 0px 1rem 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to cover the shadow with ":after", here is my code:

```
#div:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:5px;
    background:#fff;
    height:38px;
    top:1px;
    right:-5px;
}
```

Comment: I used something along these lines - as long as the after has some height and a background it works fine

Answer (score 4):

The following code did it for me to make a shadow inset of the right side:

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 10px -10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 10px -10px #000;
box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 10px -10px #000;
```

Hope it will help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and was searching for a possible idea to solve this.

I had some CSS already in place for my tabs and this is what worked for me:

(Note specifically the `padding-bottom: 2px;` inside `#tabs #selected a {`. That hides the bottom `box-shadow` neatly and worked great for me with the following CSS.)

```
#tabs {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
#tabs li a {
    padding: 1 1em;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
#tabs #selected {
    /* For the "selected" tab */
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #666666;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
#tabs #selected a {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
#tabs ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#tabs li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Thought I'd put this out there as another possible solution for anyone perusing SO for this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but none of these answers helped me, so I'm adding my answer.  This, like @yichengliu's answer, uses the Pseudo `::after` element.

```
#div {
    position: relative;
}



#div::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

/*or*/

.filter.right::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    z-index: -1;

    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaketr00/phyystqo/)

If you decide to change the X of the drop shadow (first pixel measurement of the `drop-shadow` or `box-shadow`), changing the width will help so it doesn't look like there is a white gap between the div and the shadow.

If you decide to change the Y of the drop shadow (second pixel measurement of the `drop-shadow` or `box-shadow`), changing the height will help for the same reason as above.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Old indeed and one of my best questions on here. :)

Comment: replace  **width: 1;** to **width: 1px;**  )

Answer (score 1):

I fixed such a problem by putting a div down the nav link

```
 <div [ngClass]="{'nav-div': tab['active']}"></div>
```

and giving this css to it.

```
.nav-div {
    width: inherit;
    position: relative;
    height: 8px;
    background: white;
    top: 4px
  }
```

and nav link css as

```
 .nav-link {
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;

    &.active {
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0 1px 4px -1px;
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a separate answer because it is radically different.

You could use rgba and set the alpha channel low (to get transparency) to make your drop shadow less noticeable.

Try something like this (play with the .5)

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 7px rbga(230, 230, 230, .5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px -4px 7px rbga(230, 230, 230, .5);
box-shadow: 0px -4px 7px rbga(230, 230, 230, .5);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks :) The client uses Firefox and I checked it out with your suggestion, unfortunately it made it more noticeable. I think what I finally ended up with (see comment to my question) is the closest I'm going to get. But I'm going to experiment with your answer a bit, will probably be useful on future projects. Thanks again :)

Comment: Browsers supporting box-shadow also support rgba! :p

Answer (score 0):

```
#div:before {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 background:#fff;
 height:38px;
 top:1px;
 right:-5px;
}
```