# How to create box-shadow only on left, right and bottom?

Tags: css

I tried to find solution (tricks) how to use box-shadow on left, right and bottom. I can only manage to find left, right and bottom at [CSS3 Box Shadow on Top, Left, and Right Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909561/css3-box-shadow-on-top-left-and-right-only).

I tried to change the value base on that, but unfortunately, it didn't work out. So if anyone has the solution already, please kindly provide it. Thank you.

With Regards,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry everyone,

I just found out the answer by using the following code.

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100,100,100);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100,100,100);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100,100,100);
```

Comment: I guess one problem with this solution is that it will create a shadow that is uneven, i.e. 8px on the left and right and 3px + 8px = 11px on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple shadows without blur and spread radius

```css
box-shadow: 
    /* Bottom shadow */
    0px 1px 0px black,
    
    /* Left shadow */
    -1px 0px 0px black,
    
    /* Right shadow */
    1px 0px 0px black,
    
    /* No top shadow */
    0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

This is equivalent to 1px solid black border to the top, left and right.