# CSS3 box shadow only on top left and right corners

Tags: css

I need to create this shadow effect for a client but can't figure out how it could be done:

[image]

Is this even possible with pure CSS?

**EDIT:** Here is my current CSS:

```
box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #fff, 
            0 -1px 15px #ccc, 
            0 0px 0px #fff, 
            0 0px 0px #fff;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #fff, 
                    0 -1px 15px #ccc, 
                    0 0px 0px #fff, 
                    0 0px 0px #fff;

-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #fff, 
                 0 -1px 15px #ccc, 
                 0 0px 0px #fff, 
                 0 0px 0px #fff;
```

Comment: I don't think there's a pure CSS way of doing this.

Comment: did you find the answer that you were looking for?

Comment: No, I never did. I ended up just using a border-image to solve my issue. Kind of a hack, but it was the only solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

this other answer that I stole from [Another Stack OverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909561/css3-box-shadow-on-top-left-and-right-only?rq=1)

use the spread value...

box-shadow has the following values

```
box-shadow: x y blur spread color;
```

so you could use something like..

```
box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px -10px black;
```

**here is another answer from the same Question**

You can give multiple values to box-shadow property 
    eg

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px 0px #000,
                0px -10px 12px 0px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px 0px #000,
                0px -10px 12px 0px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 12px 0px #000,
        0px -10px 12px 0px #000;
```

it is drop shadow to left and right only, you can adapt it to your requirements

**EDIT**

I was looking that the OP's Post and I think that if you tried this,

```
box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #fff, 
        0 -1px 15px #ccc, 
        0 0px 0px #fff, 
        0 -1px 15px #ccc;
```

I think that it should show the way that you are thinking it should.

I assume that the values go in Clockwise Order like Borders or margins or whatever,

```
Attribute: top, right, bottom, left;
```

and that you should be able to add a value to the left as you would with the right. 
you might have to play around with it a little bit though.

Comment: It's nice but he asked about making the shadow only at the corners, not the entire sides.

Comment: I haven't tested the last part of this answer but it seems like it would do the trick, if there was a fiddle I would be able to test it on the OP's Terms